# Animating Element Height with ScrollTop of Parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to grow a div's height respectively with the scroll position. So When I scroll down, the div grows in height, when I scroll up back up, the div's height gets smaller.

This code below works (I got from this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/AFTef/2/). However, I need it to calculate the amount of pixels not from the page top but from a parent div "#parent".

```
$(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function() {    
        var $myDiv = $('#myDiv');    
        var st = $(this).scrollTop();
        $myDiv.height( st );         
        if( st == 0 ) {              
            $myDiv.hide();
        } else {
            $myDiv.show();
        }
    })
    .scroll();                     
})
```

Comment: You don't have an element with the ID #parent ?

Comment: I know, my question is how to modify the code above to calculate pixels from a parent div rather than from page top. Does that make sense?

Comment: have you tried doing $('#parent').scrollTop() instead of $(this).scrollTop()?

Comment: `$(this).position().top` gets you the position from the top of the parent, but that scrolls as well, so the distance won't change? Otherwise you'd just do `$('#myDiv').parent()` to get the parent element ?

Comment: @blh83 that didn't work.

Comment: @adeneo that doesn't quite do it. I'm not trying to get the position of my parent div. I'm trying to get the scroll distance from the top of my parent (which increases when you scroll down away from the parent top). Make sense?